# R/quantmod using getSymbols to get closed prices from csv file with specified date

Tags: r, csv, quantmod

Trying to fetch the closing prices from a list of tickers listed in a csv. file using the following code:

```
date <- "2017-03-03"
tickers <- read.csv("us_tickerfeed.csv", header = TRUE)

for(i in 1:nrow(tickers)){
    data <- getSymbols(tickers$ticker_th[i], from = date, to = date, src = "yahoo")
    tickers$close_price[i] <- Cl(get(data))[[1]]
}
```

these codes worked before but now I'm getting the following error message:

> Error in do.call(paste("getSymbols.", symbol.source, sep = ""), list(Symbols = current.symbols,  : 
>     could not find function "getSymbols.6"

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the output from `sessionInfo()`, `getDefaults()`, and `getSymbolLookup()` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem previously, could you try `as.character(tickers$ticker_th)`?